# Why Visual Studio hides certain folders in a codeless C# project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

**Visual Studio version**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.4

**Description**

I have a very simple custom SDK style project here (https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/HiddenFolders):

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   Directory.Build.props
│   Directory.Build.targets
│   LegacyFrontEnd.sln
│
└───Approvals
    │   Approvals.csproj
    │
    ├───Content
    │       approvals_icons.png
    │
    ├───Scripts
    │       Approvals.ts
    │
    └───StaticViews
            Approvals.html
```

My problem is that VS Solution Explorer does not show the `Scripts` folder:

[image]

The build code is trivial, but it replaces the standard build targets of the SDK:

**Directory.Build.props**

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultItems>False</EnableDefaultItems>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\**\*.ts" />
    <Stylus Include="Stylus\**\*.styl" />
    <Content Include="Content\**\*.*" />
    <Content Include="StaticViews\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Directory.Build.targets**

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Build" />
  <Target Name="Clean" />
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build" />

  <Target Name="CompileTypeScript" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_jsCompiled"/>
    <Touch Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_jsCompiled\Approvals.js" AlwaysCreate="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**.\Approvals\Approvals.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Very simple.

Why does VS Solution Explorer not show the **Scripts** folder?

P.S.

Also posted here - https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/7941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild projects produce many many items of different types. It does not show all these items in Solution Explorer. It only shows certain types.

`TypeScriptCompile` items are not shown in the tree. If you want to see them in the tree, you have two options.

1. Alias them as a different type that is shown, such as `None`. You have to do this after all source items have been added:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="@(TypeScriptCompile)" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. Tell VS that `TypeScriptCompile` items are to be considered as project items:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <AvailableItemName Include="TypeScriptCompile" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of items in Solution Explorer is controlled by the Visible metadata on the items.

You can have

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Foo>
        <Visible>false</Visible>  
    </Foo>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

to hide all Foo items from solution explorer, and you can include with the metadata to control visibility:

```xml
<Stylus Include="Stylus\**\*.styl">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</Stylus>
```

or use the Update to update existing items to add, set or remove metadata:

```xml
<Stylus Update="Stylus\**\*.styl">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</Stylus>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I need the items to be visible, not hidden. I used your code with `true` instead of `false`, of course.

Comment: I have committed the minimal reproduction to github (https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/HiddenFolders) and reworked the description.